# stop duplicacy in List

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid where several dropdown, what I want is, when the user inserts new data, checking whether there's identical data already in our list.

my code is like this

```
if(ViewState["_priceSystems"]!=null)
    _priceSystems=ViewState["_priceSystems"] as TList<PriceSystemItems>;

bool _isTrue=
    PriceSystemExist(
        _priceSystemItems.PricePlanId,
        _priceSystemItems.SurchargePlanId,
        _priceSystemItems.NoMatchAltPlanId);

if(_isTrue==false) {
    _priceSystems.Add(_priceSystemItems);
}
```

Here i am adding value in the _priceSystems List<> and below code i am checking the value is exist in list or not

```
public bool PriceSystemExist(
    int PricePlanId, int SurchagePlanId, int _noPlaneId) {
    bool isExits=false;

    if(ViewState["_priceSystems"]!=null)
        _priceSystems=ViewState["_priceSystems"] as TList<PriceSystemItems>;
    try {
        if(_priceSystems!=null) {
            foreach(PriceSystemItems item in _priceSystems) {
                if(
                    item.PricePlanId==_priceSystemItems.PriceSystemId
                    &&
                    item.ServiceTypeId==_priceSystemItems.ServiceTypeId
                    &&
                    item.NoMatchAltPlanId==_priceSystemItems.NoMatchAltPlanId) {
                    isExits=true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
    }

    return isExits;
}
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong to check value in the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

change the comparision method as

```
   public bool PriceSystemExist(int PricePlanId, int SurchagePlanId, int _noPlaneId)
   {
      bool isExits = false;
      if (ViewState["_priceSystems"] != null)
      _priceSystems = ViewState["_priceSystems"] as TList<PriceSystemItems>;
    try
    {
      if(_priceSystems != null)
      {
          foreach (PriceSystemItems item in _priceSystems)
         {
            if (item.PricePlanId == PricePlanId &&  item.ServiceTypeId == SurchagePlanId && item.NoMatchAltPlanId ==  _noPlaneId)
        {
            isExits = true;
        }
     }
  }

 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {

 }

 return isExits;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using your parameters in `PriceSystemExist(int PricePlanId, int SurchagePlanId, int _noPlaneId)` method.

Use

```
PricePlanId
SurchagePlanId 
_noPlaneId
```

instead of

```
_priceSystemItems.PriceSystemId
_priceSystemItems.ServiceTypeId
_priceSystemItems.NoMatchAltPlanId
```

in your conditional.

```
foreach (PriceSystemItems item in _priceSystems)
{
        if (item.PricePlanId == PricePlanId && 
            item.ServiceTypeId == SurchagePlanId && 
            item.NoMatchAltPlanId == _noPlaneId)
        {
            isExits = true;
        }
 }
```

And you don't want to be mixing your _ prefixes.